# Problems with web.config and site.map

Tags: asp.net

i'm having some problems with one page, i've the page on web.config and site.map with deny "*", but if i write the  url the page still will open...

like this :

site.map

```
<siteMapNode url="" title="" roles="RegraTeste" description="My Page">
  <siteMapNode url="~/TelaTeste.aspx" title="Tela teste" description="Tela de teste" roles="RegraTeste" deny ="*"/>
```

web.config

```
 <location path="/TelaTeste.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="RegraTeste" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

There is something wrong with my code?

This page  supposedly is not to open if the user do not have the role: RegraTeste.

Thanks.

Comment: Try taking the `/` out of the web.config path: `<location path="TelaTeste.aspx">`

Comment: Already tryed, the problem continues.